# Remove space in line

Tags: bash, variables, grep

I am using the command "iw mlan0 link" which returns :

```
    SSID: GUEST
    freq: 2462
    RX: 4720 bytes (29 packets)
    TX: 5402 bytes (21 packets)
    signal: -53 dBm
    tx bitrate: 26.0 MBit/s MCS 3

    bss flags:      short-slot-time
    dtim period:    2
    beacon int:     100
```

How to grep the freq line or other one and remove the space ahead of the first term ?

```
iw mlan0 link | grep signal
```

returns

```
    signal: -53 dBm
```

and I would

```
signal: -53 dBm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iw mlan0 link | grep signal | sed -r 's/^\s+//g'
```

Comment: Though `sed | grep` is an antipattern.  You could write `iw wlan0 link | sed -n '/signal/s/^\s*//p'`.  Also the `/g` flag is obviously spurious; there can only be one match.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the initial spaces from each grepped line using `sed`:

```
iw mlan0 link | grep signal | sed -e 's/^ \+//'
```

Comment: Sorry, I obtain the same thing by using sed as you advice